# How to display current progress of upload (jquery + post + php)?

Tags: jquery, image, post, upload, progress

I have a problem. I'm trying to upload a image via jquery & post method + PHP to my server.
Piece of code below:

```
$.post("http://www.xyz.com/upload.php", { image: ImageObject}, function(data) {
  //code                       
});
```

I would like to display current progress (automatic updated) of upload by text, something like this:

```
<div>Current progress: <div id="progress">[dynamic number]</div>
```

Any ideas how can I do that ? I don't want to use flash - only php / jquery.

Comment: The only way would be to make a request to the server every x miliseconds checking the progress using server-side code. By the way.. does that .post even work? I didn't think you could send images with jquery's ajax methods.

Comment: Yes, post works correctly (base64). The problem is, that I don't know how to get current progress of upload :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do this natively through jQuery alone since client-side javascript has no access to client information outside of the webpage, but you *do* have a few options:

1. Use a Flash or Java plugin that has access to the client like [this one](http://swfupload.org/).
2. Use a system of polling your server to request the progress of the current file.  I am not very familiar with PHP, but in .NET the class responsible for receiving uploaded files will tell me how many bytes have been uploaded so far.  I would set a client-side timer to request that information via ajax at a given interval (1 second for example) and then use the returned information to manipulate a progress bar.
3. Use HTML5 web sockets to *push* upload progress from the server to
   the client.  Although it's a pretty neat option, it's my least
   favorite because it is harder to implement and does not enjoy wide
   browser support just yet.

Good Luck!